# Pass android.nfc.Tag via aidl?

Tags: android, nfc, aidl

I have got a simple aidl interface working:

```
package local.test;

interface ITest {
    int[] getSupportedAidlLevels();
}
```

However I am struggling to pass the non primitive type **android.nfc.Tag** which already implements **parcelable**.

```
package local.test;

interface ITest {
    int[] getSupportedAidlLevels();
    void updateNfcTag(Tag tag);
}
```

I have tried to use an *import* statement like I would in java. Further I tried to create a second *.aidl* file like the following but non of this solved my problem.

```
package local.test;
import android.nfc.Tag;
parcelable Tag;
```

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error I finally found the mistake. The **in** tag was missing.

```
package local.test;

interface ITest {
    int[] getSupportedAidlLevels();
    void updateNfcTag(in Tag tag);
}
```

Maybe this answer helps someone else ;)